# Adding custom footer buttons to Google Maps Marker on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

When I click on a Marker inside a MapFragment, two buttons appear on the bottom of the map (for route and search). How can I customize those buttons?

I searched for some tips here but only find how to add buttons to the info window...

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the [Google Map Utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) library helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FrameLayout` with 3 children, and set the `android:visibility` of the bottom buttons to `invisible`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

(If you dont set the `android:visibility="invisible"`, you can see these 2 buttons in the bottom of your mapFragment, see image below)

[image]

In your `onMarkerClick` method, you can change the invisibility of the these 2 buttons to visible, sample code:

```
button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: The point is that the map control has some buttons with a particular style and position, therefore I guessed it should be an "official" way to customize them.

Comment: did you find how to do that?

Comment: @rbaprado I dont think there are methods to add route or search buttons for mapFragment directly, you have to make your own buttons.